Cannot use an AbstractValue holding a list of PointClouds as an AbstractPort or AbstractState
I'm trying to use a list of pydrake.perception.PointClouds as an AbstractValue for an AbstractOutputPort/AbstractInputPort/AbstractState of a LeafSystem. Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to be supported.
For example,
abstract_point_cloud = AbstractValue.Make([PointCloud(0) for _ in range(5)])
self.DeclareAbstractInputPort("block_pcds", abstract_point_cloud)

However, the above yields the following error:
File ~/miniconda3/envs/drake/lib/python3.11/copy.py:146, in deepcopy(x, memo, _nil)
    144 copier = _deepcopy_dispatch.get(cls)
    145 if copier is not None:
--> 146     y = copier(x, memo)
    147 else:
    148     if issubclass(cls, type):

File ~/miniconda3/envs/drake/lib/python3.11/copy.py:206, in _deepcopy_list(x, memo, deepcopy)
    204 append = y.append
    205 for a in x:
--> 206     append(deepcopy(a, memo))
    207 return y

File ~/miniconda3/envs/drake/lib/python3.11/copy.py:161, in deepcopy(x, memo, _nil)
    159 reductor = getattr(x, "__reduce_ex__", None)
    160 if reductor is not None:
--> 161     rv = reductor(4)
    162 else:
    163     reductor = getattr(x, "__reduce__", None)

TypeError: cannot pickle 'pydrake.perception.PointCloud' object

Note that if I provide a single point cloud, this works as expected.
Thank you in advance

At first glance, it looks like PointCloud bindings don't have the requisite "copy/deep copy" feature.

The missing binding has been added now, available in the nightly build:
https://drake.mit.edu/pip.html#nightly-releases

I've PR'd the missing binding:
https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/pull/22116
